# file_put_contents(C:\storage\framework\views/27f511f5644086daa68b2cf835bf49f5148aba43.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel

so i keep getting this error on my live server but not on my local host, everything works normal on my localhost but when i deploy my website on online server it keep giving me this error

> file_put_contents(C:\appname\storage\framework\views/27f511f5644086daa68b2cf835bf49f5148aba43.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

i tried `php artisan config:cache` but nothing really worked

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong path. Does the server actually have this path `C:\appname\storage\framework\views"?

Comment: Is your live server a windows  or Unix server? If its unix this `C:\appname\storage\framework\views` defintely does not exist

Comment: @Exit no i changed it for this question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Unix and i changed it for this question

Comment: Then `C:` is not a Unix concept. there are no drives in Unix the disk storage all hangs of a logical root folder. You cannot write Windows specific code and expect it to run on Unix

Comment: @RiggsFolly the folders are like this public_html/mydomain.com/content/resources/views i don't know why the error is showing my localhost folders

Comment: I think there is wrong with the way you put it in the hosting site. you should not put all your files in the public_html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your issue is due to the [Laravel Configuration Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching).I suggest you

1. Remove the configuration cache file
2. Flush the application cache
3. Create a cache file for faster configuration loading

To do this, run the following Artisan commands on your command line

1. php artisan config:clear
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan config:cache

Where you don't have access to the command line on your server, you can [programmatically execute commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands) like this:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE'; //Return anything
});
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you have the wrong path being used, so try this to ensure that regardless of the server, you will have the right path:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
file_put_contents($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'27f511f5644086daa68b2cf835bf49f5148aba43.php');
```

This assumes that you are trying to write to the same folder as the code file that is running this.

You can also use the following to determine exactly what the path is on each server:

```
echo getcwd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your storage/ directory is not writable. Laravel requires that directory to be writable.

If you're on linux/mac, run this

chmod 0755 storage/ -R

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try and use next command `"php artisan cache:clear"` will help you to clear cache for app