# Laravel error: file_put_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel

I have uploaded my Laravel project to shared hosting, but upon navigating to the website, i am getting the following error:

```
file_put_contents(C:\Users\username\Documents\ProjectName\site\storage\framework/sessions/MCjepvHYO7Ee7RAjHmY4azKuQx97TwrrkOw288W3): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It seems like it is pointing to a local folder. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the configuration cache?

Comment: Clearing the cache did the trick! I'll post an answer of what I did for future users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I needed to clear the Laravel cache on the server. I added the following to my `routes/web.php` file to run the command on my hosting server:

```
// Clearing Laravel Configuration Cache
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE'; //Return anything
});
```

And then navigated to `mywebsiteurl.com/clear-cache` to run the commands. Once it was done, I received a 500 error. After that, I was able to navigate to `mywebsiteurl.com` and my website loaded as expected.

I got the answer from the one accepted here: [file_put_contents(C:\storage\framework\views/27f511f5644086daa68b2cf835bf49f5148aba43.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287758/file-put-contentsc-storage-framework-views-27f511f5644086daa68b2cf835bf49f5148)